# How to merge two branches based on tag versions in git?

Tags: git, github

I am new to the git I have created three branches like master and dev and feature branch.

in feature branch I have committed my code 3 times, so I have three commit ids like "cd5e009d3f9ba4c058b0f9aXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX".

now I have used tag option in my feature branch like below

```
> git tag v1.0 
>git push origin v1.0
```

as per my under standing I have using tags we created version.

Now I want to merge all code changes from  my feature branch tag version v1.0 to dev branch based on tag.

Comment: How is merging "based on tag" different from just merging feature into dev?

Answer (score 0):

Git branches and tags merely point at a commit. Simply merge the tag.

```
git checkout dev
git merge v1.0
```

- Unless there are more commits to feature after you tagged, this is equivalent to `git merge feature`. Both `feature` and `v1.0` point at the same commit.
- Generally, one does not tag a feature branch with a version. You merge the feature branch, delete the feature branch, then tag when you release. See [Feature Branch Workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow).

Comment: What if I have a commit ahead of my tag..And I want merge that tag..i.e., I have two tags v1.0 and v2.0... And my branch is at v2.0 and I want to merge v1.0

Comment: @Sai Merge the tag. But again, this is not a good way to use feature branches. They should be all-or-nothing. Once merged, delete the branch and open another one.

Comment: Generally, one does not tag a feature branch with a version. You merge the feature branch, delete the feature branch, then tag when you release. See Feature Branch Workflow.------Yeah you are right but I took it as example to ask question. Thanks for quick reply...